# How Can I Transfer Text From Input Box to Text Area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a prototype for a chat client. At this stage, I'm just learning how to append the user's input to the text area above. However, no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to work. The only time it actually functioned correctly was in jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work when I load my actual HTML page.

It's worth mentioning that, at the advice of a tutorial, I already tried placing the script tag for my JQuery code at the end of the body instead of in the head. The tutorial said that it was essential for all elements be allowed to load before the JQuery code, so that's the way it had to be. As you can see below, the script tags are currently in the head, but that doesn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ChatStyle.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Chat.js"></script>
<title>
    Chat Client Prototype
</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div ID="topBar">
    </div>

    <h2 ID="header">Chat Client</h2>

    <div ID="chatBox">
        <div ID="topBar2">
        </div>

        <div ID="header2">
            Chat Client
        </div>

        <textarea ID="textArea" name="textArea">
        </textarea>

            <form ID="in">
                <input ID="textField" type="text">
                <button ID="send" type="button" name="Send" value="send">Send</button>
            </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Chat.js

```
function sendText(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send').click(function () {
        var text = $('#textField').val();
        $('#textArea').val($('#textArea').val() + text);
        $('#textField').val('');
    });
});
}
```

Comment: I see you are missing `http://` infront of `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @SrinivasR no, missing protocol name will allow both type http or https, this is how CDN works

Comment: @SrinivasR that's irrelevant unless working from the filesystem. It's a relative protocol, similar to leaving off the domain to get a link that targets current domain.

Comment: SrinivasR was right. That seemed to fix the problem for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Don't wrap document ready handler inside sendText() function, use that instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send').click(sendText);
});

function sendText(){
    var text = $('#textField').val();
    $('#textArea').val($('#textArea').val() + text);
    $('#textField').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it work if you change your button to submit type and bind the event to form submit:

```
$('#in').submit(function () {
    var text = $('#textField').val();
    $('#textArea').val($('#textArea').val() + text);
    $('#textField').val('');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AztSB/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to put it in a function. You can just leave it to Jquery :)

Your stuff in a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9qYC3/) to see

Jquery:

```
$('#send').click(function () {
    var text = $('#textField').val();
    $('#textArea').append(text);
    $('#textField').val('');
});
```

[UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/9qYC3/1/)

Use append() to update the textarea with new text!

Comment: That would _replace_ the text in the textarea for the text in the text field. He wants to append it at the end.

Comment: See that now, just changed it to append()

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ChatStyle.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send').click(function () {
        var text = $('#textField').val();
        $('#textArea').html($('#textArea').html() + text);
        $('#textField').val('');
    });
});
</script>
<title>
    Chat Client Prototype
</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ID="topBar">
</div>

<h2 ID="header">Chat Client</h2>

<div ID="chatBox">
    <div ID="topBar2">
    </div>

    <div ID="header2">
        Chat Client
    </div>

    <textarea ID="textArea" name="textArea"></textarea>

        <form ID="in">
            <input ID="textField" type="text">
            <input ID="send" type="button" name="Send" value="send"/>
        </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't wrap it in your function `sendText`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send').click(function () {
        var text = $('#textField').val();
        $('#textArea').val($('#textArea').val() + text);
        $('#textField').val('');
    });
});
```